# _.findWhere() in PHP?

Tags: php, underscore.js

What is the php implementation of underscore's `_.findWhere({key:'val'})`?

This is how the method is documented by [Underscorejs.org](http://underscorejs.org/):

> _.findWhere(list, properties)
>
> Looks through the list and returns the first value that matches all of the key-value pairs listed in properties.

Comment: I don't think this is implemented in PHP, this closest thing searches scalar values is array_search http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: array_filter is another alternative.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 0):

I wrote these little functions. Might be handy.

```
function where($list, $props)
{
    $result = array_filter(
    $list,
    function ($e) use ($props)
    {
        $count = 0;
    foreach ($props as $key => $value) 
    {
        if ($value == $e[$key]) 
        {
            $count += 1;
        }
        return $count == count($props);
    }
    }
    );
    return $result;
}

function findWhere($list, $props)
{
    $result = where($list, $props);
    return array_values($result)[0];
}
```

Answer (score -4):

There is none. Underscore is a collection of functions written in JS. It has nothing to do with PHP.